# openshift readiness probe error: /bin/sh can't access tty; job control turned off

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

My readiness probe is like /bin/sh -i -c 'readiness_cmd_line_blabla',

but I always get error like /bin/sh can't access tty; job control turned off

Any idea why ?

The docker image base container is alpine:3.5, and I'm using openshift-origin 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readiness probes do not allocate a TTY when they connect - it seems likely that is related.